# Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) sql exception

Tags: javascript, mysql, mysql-workbench

can't able to connect with mysql and eclipse after running the server login success is not showing..showing only the empty page

tried to change with different  username and password

Comment: Your username and/or password is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to SQL server from workbench or similar software and then use correct data for the app to access SQL.